# spark jobserver ERROR classnotfoundexception

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, classpath, apache-spark-sql, spark-jobserver

I have been trying spark using spark-shell. All my data is in sql.

```
  I used to include external jars using the --jars flag like /bin/spark-shell --jars /path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar --master spark://sparkmaster.com:7077

  I have included it in class path by changing  the bin/compute-classpath.sh file 
  I was running succesfully with this config.
```

Now when I am running a standalone job through jobserver. I am getting the following error message

```
result: {
    "message" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    "errorClass" : "java.lang.classNotFoundException"
    "stack" :[.......]
}
```

I have included the jar file in my local.conf file as below. 
   context-settings{
     .....
   dependent-jar-uris = ["file:///absolute/path/to/the/jarfile"]
    ......
   }

Answer (score 2):

All of your dependencies should be included in your `spark-jobserver` application JAR (e.g. create an "uber-jar"), or be included on the classpath of the Spark executors.  I recommend configuring the classpath, as it's faster and requires less disk-space since the third-party library dependencies don't need to be copied to each worker whenever your application runs.

Here are the steps to configure the worker (executor) classpath on Spark 1.3.1:

1. Copy the third-party JAR(s) to each of your Spark workers and the Spark master
2. Place the JAR(s) in the same directory on each host (e.g. /home/ec2-user/lib
3. Add the following line to the Spark `/root/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` file on the Spark master:

   `spark.executor.extraClassPath /root/ephemeral-hdfs/conf:/home/ec2-user/lib/name-of-your-jar-file.jar`

   Here's an example of my own modifications to use the Stanford NLP library:

   `spark.executor.extraClassPath /root/ephemeral-hdfs/conf:/home/ec2-user/lib/stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar:/home/ec2-user/lib/stanford-corenlp-3.4.1-models.jar`

Answer (score 0):

You might not be having `/path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` in your workers.
You can either copy required dependency to all spark workers or 
`Bundle the submitting jar with required dependencies`.

 I use maven for building the jar. The scope of dependencies must be run-time.

Answer (score 0):

`curl --data-binary @/PATH/jobs_jar_2.10-1.0.jar 192.168.0.115:8090/jars/job_to_be_registered`

For posting dependency jar

`curl -d "" 'http://192.168.0.115:8090/contexts/new_context?dependent-jar-uris=file:///path/dependent.jar'`

This works for jobserver 1.6.1